# Angular UI calendar integration - Events from resource not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am facing a very strange problem with Angular UI Calendar.
I am trying to load some events from an api and put them into the calendar.
Events are showed correctly when the page is first loaded. But when I click on the next month button and come back to the previous month, I see that events which were loaded statically are still there, but events loaded from the API have disappeared, despite the scope values haven't changed !
From HTML side :

```
<div class="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar"></div>
```

From Angular JS controller Side :

```
appApp.controller('AgendaCtrl',
    function($scope,$resource,uiCalendarConfig){
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        $scope.eventSources = new Array();

        var Event = $resource($scope.rootPath + 'events/:id.json', {token: $scope.user.token}, {
            'update': {method: 'PUT'}
        });

        $scope.uiConfig = {
            calendar:{
                editable: false,
                header:{
                    left: 'title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'today prev,next'
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.events = [
                {title: 'All Day Event',start: new Date(2015, 10, 1)}
            ];
        $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];

        $scope.evts = Event.get({user_id: $scope.user.id},function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.evts.Events.length; i++) {
                //Date conv.
                var t = $scope.evts.Events[i].Event.start.split(/[- :]/);
                $scope.evts.Events[i].Event.start = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
                var t = $scope.evts.Events[i].Event.end.split(/[- :]/);
                $scope.evts.Events[i].Event.end = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
                $scope.eventSources[0].push($scope.evts.Events[i].Event);
            };
        });
    });
```

The "All day event", which is hard coded in the controller, shows correctly in any case. But the events from $scope.evts are showed only on first load, but disappear when I change the month and come back to the right month.

Any idea on why ? I would like to have my events correctly showed, even if I switch months.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what happened.
I changed my code like this and it worked fine...

```
timmApp.controller('AgendaCtrl',
function($scope,$resource){
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    $scope.eventSources = new Array();
    $scope.eventApi = new Array();

    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
            editable: false,
            header:{
                left: 'title',
                center: '',
                right: 'today prev,next'
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.events = {
        url : $scope.rootPath + "events/index.json",
        type : 'GET',
        data: {  
           user_id: $scope.user.id,
           token: $scope.user.token
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //Date conv.
            for (var i = 0; i < data.events.length; i++) {
                //Date conv.
                var t = data.events[i].start.split(/[- :]/);
                data.events[i].start = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
                var t = data.events[i].end.split(/[- :]/);
                data.events[i].end = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
            };
            return data.events;
        }
    }; 
    $scope.eventSources = [$scope.events];
}
```

);

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is to use stick property of even:
stick: true - event will be cached
stick: false (default) - not cached

sample code, where all added events will be cached:

```
addEvents: (data) ->
@events.push { title: item.name, start: new Date(item.when), info: item.info, stick: true} for item in data
```